# Unity game crashes on iOS but not on Android

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, crash

I have made app that takes picture of screen and saves it in Gallery with name i have given using DateTime class and my own prefix. The code on Android works perfect,when you press the button it takes the screenshot and it finishes everything.
But the story is not the same on iOS. It crashes when ever the button is pressed.This is the code :

```
Flash.SetActive(true);
RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(resWidth, resHeight, 24);
cam.targetTexture = rt;
Texture2D screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidth, resHeight, 
TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
cam.Render();
RenderTexture.active = rt;
screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0);
cam.targetTexture = null;
RenderTexture.active = null;
Destroy(rt);
byte[] bytes = screenShot.EncodeToPNG();
filename = ScreenShotName(resWidth, resHeight);

FullSharePath = "/storage/emulated/0/GarderobaShots/" + filename + ".png";

Texture2D textu = new Texture2D(900,1320, TextureFormat.RGBAFloat, false);
textu.LoadImage(bytes);
textu.Apply();
spr = Sprite.Create(textu ,new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, textu.width, textu.height), 
new Vector2(1f, 1f), 100.0f);

ShareAbleObject.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.GetComponent<Image> 
().sprite = spr;
ShareAbleObject.SetActive(true);
NativeGallery.SaveImageToGallery(textu, "AmazingGirlsShots", filename + ".png");

takeHiResShot = false;
```

Just a quick introduction to code
It switches MainCamera of scene with some camera i have(its smaller and it has different canvas(only text)) then it activates object i have called Flash which is white flash on screen,it goes of by itself
Afterwards it render texture from screen and saves it in

Texture2D textu

Full Share path is path where this file will be stored so the user wants, he can share it or see it from game

```
NativeGallery.SaveImageToGallery(textu, "AmazingGirlsShots", 
filename".png");
```

It's plugin i took for ios and android that refreshes gallery for image to be shown in gallery,otherwise its just somewhere in phone
I think that cant be problem as its check plugin that many people use

Comment: can you please share a stack trace ?

Comment: @Mosbah Sorry,what is stack trace? Console on xcode? Im not experienced apple programmer,this is my first app actually.

Comment: @Mosbah here is the stack trace

Comment: Started Taking ScreenShot
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
ScreenShotScript:TakeHiResScreen()
ScreenShotScript:LateUpdate()
 
(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)

Comment: That does not tell much, sorry I'm out of ideas

Comment: @Mosbah no problem,ill fix it oncr